# Drools filtering stream within DRL

Tags: drools

I would like to create a rule with lamba expression like below:

```
when 
rule_id: String() from "784acba8-32e5-41de-bd73-04f9ce2bfaff"
$: DroolsEventWrapper(Arrays.stream("testing".split("")).filter(element->(element!=null && element.contains("e"))).findFirst().isPresent())
then 
System.out.println("Qualified for "+rule_id);
end
```

just a simple check "testing" will be given as a parameter also; however when I use it drl. It gave error like:

```
mismatched input '.' in rule "784acba8-32e5-41de-bd73-04f9ce2bfaff" in pattern
```

When I check the location of that dot; it belongs to **filter(element->(element!=null && element.contains("e")))** when I omit it, it is working.

I am using the latest version of Drools: 7.55.0.Final. I found some tickets which say that lambda expressions somehow buggy at previous versions but not the latest ones.

Do I missing something, or is there any way to run this within DRL ?

Comment: If you just want to test if a string contains a letter, why don't you use a regex? `str matches ".*?e.*"`

Comment: Actually string is just for testing; any type of stream; I try to filter

Comment: But why? Drools already exposes powerful filter capabilities for all iterables. Can you provide a real use case where the Drools built-in support (including collect, accumulate, etc) are insufficient?